# Spring security how to allow anonymous access to most of site restricting certain actions

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'd like to have a similar behavior to Stack Overflow where you can see most of the site anonymously and only requires a user role/authentication for certain actions.  Basically anonymous read with restricted writes. 
What I was hoping I could do is specify anonymous access my security-config.xml and annotate various methods that require a proper user role.
Config:

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

Method declaration

```
    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{estabID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEstablishmentPage(@PathVariable String estabID) { .... }
```

However I am not prompted for the basic auth credentials with this configuration.  If I change the access attribute in the config to ROLE_USER everything works as expected, I'm presented with an auth challenge.

What would be the best way to accomplish anonymous access by default with authenticated users for certain actions?

Comment: It sounds like the global method security isn't being applied. Could you throw the debugger on and see if it's walking through a MethodSecurityInterceptor?

Comment: Most likely you are running into the issue covered in [this FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context). You will also find it discussed previously on SO.

Comment: @luke you're right that was exactly the issue, you want to add it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luke Taylor mentioned in his comment, the problem was fixed by following [this FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context)